# sitemap blocked by 'noindex' detected in 'X-Robots-Tag' http header

Tags: sitemap, noindex, x-robots-tag

I have the following picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1lSy.png)

I don't know when my website was like this.
I checked in htcacess and in source webiste there is no noindex in header.
In fact, even if I have deleted and reinstalled WP completely, my sitemap in webmaster tools still gives an error even though there are only 2 posts.
Sorry, this error is caused by google blocking my website.
Or for another reason.
Please just help me.

I have deleted and reinstalled the new WP website completely but still the same.

I hope to find a way to fix the above error.

Comment: this is normal https://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-noindex-detected-in-x-robots-tag-http-header-site-map-issue/